# how to use Fkeys f5 in textbox tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Respected sir
how to use F5 or f6 in tkinter text box when i press f5 the call the function and fill textbox with given data

Thank in advance for your help

regard

how to use F5 or f6 in tkinter text box when i press f5 the call the function and fill textbox with given data

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

In this, i will show how to easily refresh a tkinter text box with new data by pressing F5.

```
import tkinter as tk

def fill_textbox_with_data():
    # Hey, let's put some cool stuff in the text box!
    data = "Hey there! This is some awesome data to fill up your text box!"
    text_box.delete("1.0", tk.END)  # Clear out whatever's already there
    text_box.insert(tk.END, data)

def key_press(event):
    # Check if you hit F5, and if so, let's fill up that text box!
    if event.keysym == 'F5':
        fill_textbox_with_data()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Press F5 to Fill the Text Box!")

text_box = tk.Text(root, height=10, width=50)
text_box.pack()

# Let's make sure we're listening for those key presses in the text box
text_box.bind("<KeyPress>", key_press)

root.mainloop()
```

Pressing F5 will automatically fill your text box with interesting text.

Comment: Prashant Morey your answer is AI generated and AI generated answers are not acceptable, check out this policy for further information: [Temporary Policy: Generative AI is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)

Answer (score 0):

### Description:

The goal you are trying to achieve can be easily fulfilled using the `bind()` function. That allows users to bind a key or mouse button to run the defined function.

### Solution:

If you are using customtkinter for generating you GUI this code is suitable for you:

**For customtkinter:**

```py
import customtkinter

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry('600x500')
app.title('Stackoverflow Issue by Abdullah Qureshi')

def data_for_F5():
    textbox.delete('0.0', 'end')
    inserting_info_F5 = "This line will be inserted inside the textbox when F5 is pressed"
    textbox.insert('0.0', inserting_info_F5)
    
def data_for_F6():
    textbox.delete('0.0', 'end')
    inserting_info_F6 = "This line will be inserted inside the textbox when F6 is pressed"
    textbox.insert('0.0', inserting_info_F6)

textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(app, width=200, height=200)
textbox.place(x=10, y=10)

app.bind('<F5>', lambda event: data_for_F5())
app.bind('<F6>', lambda event: data_for_F6())

app.mainloop()
```

If you are using tkinter and want the same method to be applied in it, there are some changes that are to be made.

**For Tkinter:**

```py
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry('600x500')
app.title('Stackoverflow Issue by Abdullah Qureshi')

def data_for_F5():
    textbox.delete('1.0', 'end')
    inserting_info_F5 = "This line will be inserted inside the textbox when F5 is pressed"
    textbox.insert('1.0', inserting_info_F5)
    
def data_for_F6():
    textbox.delete('1.0', 'end')
    inserting_info_F6 = "This line will be inserted inside the textbox when F6 is pressed"
    textbox.insert('1.0', inserting_info_F6)

textbox = tk.Text(app, width=100, height=100)
textbox.place(x=10, y=10)

app.bind('<F5>', lambda event: data_for_F5())
app.bind('<F6>', lambda event: data_for_F6())

app.mainloop()
```

### Note:

It's a good practice to add a minimal reproducible code of the issue that you are facing so that people can solve it easily, I have given the above example only because your question was enough for me to understand your requirements.